# Restore MySQL Database from Wamp Folder

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp, wampserver

Is it possible to restore a MySQL database from the physical database files. I have a directory that has the following file types:

request_form.ibd
request_form.frm

Iam using Wamp Server....

Comment: Is it a MYISAM or INNODB database it sounds like an INNODB database from the files you meniton. In whicg case the data is actuallt stored in `....\data\ibdata1` do you have that also

Comment: The path you mentioned is not avialable

Comment: Then if I am right and you had INNODB tables you have unfortunately lost your database. I assume you have not got any backups?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible it's not recommended to do so if you haven't prepared a file backup with a consistent DB state.
BTW if you need to do a restore from physical files  of the DB you need to find the data directory of the dbms (I guess you're working on MySQL), stop the sql server, replace the data files with the needed ones and restart the sql server.
After that some table/indexes restoring may be needed; after fixing such problems I suggest a complete backup of the database using the proper tools (like mysqldump) and then a restore on a fresh install a using proper methods (restoring from the aforementioned mysqldump generated file)

Comment: I looked at the wamp docs and the mysql data directory should be:
`{drive_letter_where_you_installed_wamp}/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql{your_mysql_version}/data`